# How to pass variables between jobs without artifacts in Gitlab-CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pipelines

I want to pass some variables between jobs (on other stages) in my gitlab-ci scrypt. I used as in example:

```
buildTest:
    stage: build
    artifacts:
        reports:
            dotenv: build.env
        name: "FullRelease"
        paths:
            - 'app'
        expire_in: 1 day
    script: |
        echo "version=1.2.3" >> build.env
....
runWin:
    stage: runOnWin
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script: |
        echo "Version is %version%"
    needs:
        - job: buildTest
          artifacts: true
```

All is work, but I've got all artifacts from 'buildTest' (whole folder app, which is big). It's a bit strange, but it doesn't contains file 'build.env', which is only I need. Is there any possibility to pass only variables, without other artifacts. If I set artifacts: false - no variables are passed.

Comment: Just remove `paths: - 'app'` if you don't want it?

Comment: I WANT it,  but not in runWin job. I want to be able to downloand app as zip archive from web or inside other job (not runWin) to build docker image and so on.

Comment: the question is, is the content of your build.env depending on how you create the `app` folder or can this be done in a separate job - which creates just the build.env :)

Comment: Content of build.dev depends on source code, and from source code my app is built. If I divide job (one for build.dev and second for building app), then source code will be loaded twice. I want to escape this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way but you can try to call the pipeline from a job with environment variables having [GitLab pipeline API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, unfortunately. There is an open issue at GitLab with a proposal for this:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/384028

Please comment there to gain attention for this topic.